# change file timestamp format for uwsgi log rotation file

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have created a uwsgi ini for my flask application like so (this is just the snippet that is important for this question):

```
logto2 = %(base)/logs/test.log
log-maxsize = 10000000
logformat = [%(ftime)]
log-reopen = true
```

When test.log hits max size, the rotated log file gets this timestamp extension:

```
test.log.1605221780
```

I want to make the `1605221780` into a more readable format such as "YYYY-mm-dd".

Is there there a specific uwsgi ini variable to specify this? or is this accomplished outside the ini?

Thanks in advance.